# In Vim what is the difference between "+ and "* registers?

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

In Vim what is the difference between `"+` and `"*` registers? Which one should be used for copying from and pasting to Vim from other applications? Do I need to append anything in *.vimrc* file to get those two registers to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The registers are an X11 feature; they are not Linux-specific or even Unix-specific but work on any OS that uses X11.

As described in Vim documentation ([`:help quoteplus`](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html)), the `"+` register corresponds to the 'CLIPBOARD' selection in X11, while the `"*` register corresponds to the 'PRIMARY' selection.

- More detailed explanation:

  The X11 graphical environment has support for multiple clipboard-like buffers, called *selections*. There are three standard ones, two of which are in wide use:

  - The `PRIMARY` selection is updated every time you *select* text. To paste from it (in graphical programs), middle-click or use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd>. In Vim, it is accessible through the `"*` register.
  - The `CLIPBOARD` selection is updated when you *explicitly* cut or copy anything (text or other data). In other words, it is used just like the Windows or Mac OS clipboards. To paste from it, the usual shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> in grapical programs. In Vim, it is accessible through the `"+` register.

You don't need any special settings to use them; however, your Vim must be configured with X11 support (look for `+X11` in `vim --version`), and – obviously – the registers only work inside X11.

It doesn't matter whether you are using the GUI or terminal version of Vim, however. (On Arch Linux, the `gvim` package provides both GUI and terminal versions with the X11 support enabled.)

Resources:

- [X Selections, Cut Buffers, and Kill Rings](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html)
- Vim documentation: [`:help quoteplus`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#quoteplus)

Comment: What is the definition of  `X11`?

Comment: X11 aka X Window System 11 is the system and protocol used for the graphical interfaces in Linux, BSDs, most other Unix-like operating systems, as well as a few others like OpenVMS. (Surely, as a Geek, you should be able to figure that one out...)

Comment: I have been using `:r! xclip` to get what has always been in "+ and "\*. *facepalm*